# Carrying inside a body without an Eruv

Tags: shabbat, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot

At what point are bodily fluids not considered part of a person and therefore become subject to the restrictions of carrying on Shabbos?

For example, if a doctor requires a urine sample on Shabbos, or if an infant needs milk from a wet neighbor (assume for arguments sake that both of these cases are non-life threatening), is it considered carrying since the substance in question has a distinct purpose? Or is this similar in Halacha to a woman putting oil in her hair so that a neighbor can use that oil for her food on Shabbos?

This is assuming somehow the Issur of Refuah, and the Issur of holding in bodily waste are taken care of.

Comment: To be clear, I think your question is about "carrying" done inside the body.

Comment: Good point, I guess that's the gist of my question...

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%99_%D7%94

Comment: When I first saw the title, I thought for sure this was a PTIJ spin on the Mishnayos which deal with a human wall acting as part of an eruv.